# Why is it at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on one of the elements in the navigation bar, it jumps to the top of the page. I made a navigation bar and its elements: home page, news ...etc. Whichever I click, it sends me to the top of the page I made. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Well it's not a problem but a repulsion effect of magnets. Kidding you `#` value in links `href` thats why it is taking to new page top(i.e, current page top)

Comment: You're probably using `<a href="#">...</a>`

Comment: So, how can I solve this situation. I don't want it to move when I click it.

Comment: Yes, that's how I use it, even though I deleted the '#' later, the problem did not go away. Do I need to put something else instead?

Comment: No need to worry, it is not a problem. Once you developed the website, these links will take you to new page top. So just chill........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did not add a proper link.

Make sure you add the href attribute as seen below. Also, check that the href value is not **#**

```
<a href='home.html'>Home</a>
<!-- Will work -->
```

Below will take you to the top of the page

```
<a href='#'>Home</a>
<!-- Will take you to the top of the page-->
```

Comment: Thank you. What you said is correct. I noticed that the problem was fixed by deleting the href=" " tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save the `href="#"` (for example, for demonstration), then you can use `<a href='#!'>Link</a>`